# mySQL complains on duplicate key even though the table was empty

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I use Python (2.7) and I work with MySQLdb directory to control my SQL database (MySQL workbench 6)

I have a script that updates an sql table every ten minutes. The script deletes everything on the table at first and then insert all the rows again (with the updated data).
This is a sketch of my code:

```
db=MySQLdb.Connect("localhost", "admin", "admin")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("use my_scheme")
cursor.execute("delete from my_table")
for item in updated_item_list:
    cursor.execute("insert into my_table values (%s, %s, %s)", (item[0], item[1], item[2]))
    db.commit()
    cursor.fetchall()
```

Now, for some reason, I got weird behavior sometimes: the script starts updating the table and some of the rows are actually being inserted but it stops in the middle with:

```
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

Every time, different key is being picked as duplicate. How can it be? All the entries have been deleted before. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is surprising about this?  The data that you are inserting has duplicate `val1` values.  This is the way the primary key constraint works.  If you don't think this is the case, edit your question with the data being inserted.  Or, better yet, put up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: You are right. I was trying to make a sketch of my code and it wasn't so good at first try. Anyway, I am *not* inserting duplicate values into the table, update_item_list has one instance of each item. I edited the question

Comment: Get rid of the `cursor.fetchall()`, I don't even know why you have it there as you don't have a select query. Put the `db.commit()` _after_ the `DELETE` query, in addition to within your loop.

Comment: I did it. It still fails on duplicate key

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be inserting constants into the database, not your actual values.Try this.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table values " +
"(val1, val2, val3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", 
(val1, val2, val3))
```